# IIB stops reading from queue

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

Sometimes when I'm developing in IIB I notice that it stops reading anything from a queue. My work-around is to create a new queue and use it until that one stops working. I'm sure this is a feature of IIB. How do you turn it off for development work?

Comment: I never encountered such issue during my five year experience with IIB. However I would like to set the trace level of IIB and MQ to finest level to try to find the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

You must set backout destination on your JMSInput node or MQInput node.
As long as you are having some errors, it stops reading anything from a queue because you have not set backout-queue.

Answer (score 1):

Check number of listeners running to queue in open input count parameter.
In case it is 0, it means listeners aren't working, otherwise flow is stuck somewhere

Answer (score 1):

Provide more details on when exactly the flow stops reading from the queue for a specific answer. On the face of it, it appears that you may be getting an exception in your flow and the catch terminal in your MQInput Node is not connected.

If yes, follow the below steps:

1. Create another local queue.
2. Update the name of this new queue in the BOQNAME property of the original queue from which your message flow is reading.
3. Set the value of BOTHRESH in the original queue to 1.

Now all the messages that are getting an exception will be sent to the backout queue and your flow will not stop reading from the queue in case of exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your flow fails while processing messaes. In this case you will need to create a backout queue and configure you queue to move failed messages after a preconfigured threshold to allow your flow to try processing the rest of the messaes.